# ¿Cómo reproduzco un audio en Firefox con CSS y HTML?

Tags: html, css, firefox, audio

tengo que poner un audio en una pagina web, y lo he añadido usando el codigo que pongo mas abajo y en chrome y en edge se me reproduce perfectamente pero en firefox no se escucha nada y ni siquiera sale el icono de reproduccion de audio en la pestaña, alguna idea? Gracias

```
<embed src="audio/We_Wish_You.mp3" hidden="true" autoplay loop></embed>
```

He probado tambien a añadirlo como .ogg y .wav ya que se que algunos navegadores pueden tener problemas con algunos formatos de audio pero nada, no lo consigo.

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

<----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

SOLUCIONADO:

Al final me dí cuenta de que poniendo el siguiente codigo funcionaba en Chrome y Edge pero no en Firefox:

```
<embed src="audio/We_Wish_You.mp3" hidden="true" autoplay loop></embed>
```

Y con el siguiente codigo funcionaba en Firefox pero no en Chrome y en Edge:

```
<audio src="audio/We_Wish_You.ogg" autoplay> Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</audio>
```

Asi que hice como me recomendó un usuario de aquí y utilicé JavaScript para detectar que navegador era y en función agregar el audio de una manera o de otra, me quedó algo así (por si le sirve a alguien)(esta resumido, solo he puesto lo importante):

HTML:

```
<script defer src="js/main.js"></script>    
<span id="audio"></span>
```

JS:

```
function setAudio() {

let nav = window.navigator.userAgent;

if (nav.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = "<audio src=\"audio/We_Wish_You.ogg\" autoplay> Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</audio>";
} else {
    document.getElementById("audio").innerHTML = "<embed src=\"audio/We_Wish_You.mp3\" hidden=\"true\" autoplay loop></embed>";
}
}

setAudio();
```

Gracias a todos por la ayuda, un saludo!

Comment: Quizás deberías echarle un ojo a esta libreria https://howlerjs.com/

Comment: @alexmaza_wd Stack Overflow no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas (Q&A) donde hay una sección para la pregunta y otra para las respuestas. No edites la pregunta para poner “solucionado” y cómo lo hiciste; Escribe una respuesta con lo que hiciste o, si te sirvió una de las respuestas existentes, márcala como aceptada. Pásate por el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio.

Comment: Pues es raro porque tanto `embed` como `audio` funcionan en esos tres navegadores. He hecho pruebas con archivos `mp3` y `ogg` y no me han dado ningún problema.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
 <audio controls>
      <source src="audio/We_Wish_You.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay>
  Este navegador no soporta la etiqueta de <code>audio</code>.
</audio>
```

Comment: Buenas! He probado como dices y se me ponen los controles en la pantalla (que eso lo oculto luego con css) y dandole a play si que me lo reproduce, pero aun con el autoplay no se inicia automaticamente la cancion, tienes que iniciarla manualmente, alguna idea de por que? Y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el AutoPlay esta capado. Es decir: A menos que se interactúe con la pagina el audio no se reproducirá ni se mostrará.

Pero puedes saltarte esto con un iframe con la etiqueta allow.

```
<iframe src="http://miweb.com/pagina_audio.html" allow="autoplay">
```

Si no puedes probar con JavaScript que yo personalmente le veo mas uso ya que te permite controlar todo sin interacción del usuario como el volumen, autoplay, etc...

Comment: Buenas, he probado con el iframe y tampoco consigo que me funcione, y lo se, yo tambien soy partidario de usar mas javascript pero es para un trabajo del instituto y debe estar hecho todo con html y css solo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score -3):

```
<audio src="Carpeta o link donde el audio se encuentre" autoplay>    
  Your browser does not support the <code> audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, ya probé antes a añadir el audio con las etiquetas de audio pero ahi si que no me reproducia en ningun navegador

Comment: <audio src="mp3/Lana Del Rey - Video Games.mp3" autoplay="true" loop="true"></audio>

Intenta con este, a mi me funciona.

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y no me funciona eso en ningun navegador :(